# 2 list overlaping when they are placed horizontally with scroll=false

Tags: list, sencha-touch

I have 2 list i want to display it horizontally i used height 10 % for both the lists allowing it to hide rest of the content of the lists.

By Doing scroll=false for the lists and by using layout='vbox' for the parent layout both the lists are overlapped in  such case what should i do?

thanks Raj

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add these lists as an item panel and set height to those panels.
ie

```
var panel1= new Ext.Panel({
layout:'fit',
height:'10%',
items:[list1]
});

var panel2= new Ext.Panel({
layout:'fit',
height:'10%',
items:[list2]
});
```

Then add these panels to your main panel with vbox layout.